# Does jQuery in table tag allowed?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have this php-jquery-html pseudo-structure:

```
<table>
<?php while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($sth)){ ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Some HTML tag here
        </td>
    </tr>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Some jQuery here
    </script>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

and I load this with AJAX in another page.
I'm sure that `$sth` has 6 rows but it displays only 1 row. If I remove `<script>` section it works fine.
Are we allowed to do this or I should check my syntax? (I didn't have any syntax error though!)

Comment: it's not exactly a legitimate place to put a script block, by HTML standards - the only things directly inside a table should be tr/thead/tbody/tfoot/caption/colgroup.

Comment: use the firefox plugin HTML Validator(works for xhtml too) http://users.skynet.be/mgueury/mozilla/

Comment: jQuery AJAX won't parse JavaScript anyway - so you have to change the logic and send the data as HTML or pure text and parse it in the AJAX handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not valid HTML markup and could therefore cause issues with your layout.

`script` tags cannot be nested directly into `table` tags, however you can put this into your `td` tag

```
<table>
<?php while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($sth)){ ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Some HTML tag here            
            <script type="text/javascript">
                // Some jQuery here
            </script>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: There's no suggestion that XHTML is being used (although it isn't valid HTML either).

Comment: lol. w3schools is not something you need to look for reference. It is filled with junk. Refer to MDN or w3c specs instead.

Answer (score 1):

> Are we allowed to do this or

`<script>` elements are not allowed as child elements of a `<table>` or `<tbody>` element.

> I should check my syntax?

Always [check](http://validator.w3.org)

> I'm sure that $sth has 6 rows but it displays only 1 row.

Look at the HTML that is output by the PHP. Don't compare PHP to end rendering. Work out at what point in the chain the output differs from what you expect, and then compare that output to the stage immediately before it.